# How to copy a row to a specific start column and specific row?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy the whole columnnames (attributes) from the source wb and paste them into the active wb but not in row 1:1 but in row 19 starting from B19. This gave me an error:

```
sourceworkbook.Sheets("Kontrollübersicht").Range("1:1").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Kontrollübersicht").Range("B19:19").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Maybe you can help me out here.

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Values

- Most often, it is not necessary to copy whole rows or columns.
- Also, row `1` (`A1:XFD1`) contains `16384` cells, while `B19:XFD19` contains one less so it won't fit.
- When copying values, copying by assignment is the most efficient way. The only thing to remember is to resize the destination range to the size of the source range.

```vb
Dim srg As Range
With sourceworkbook.Sheets("Kontrollübersicht").Rows(1)
    Set srg = .Worksheet.Range(.Cells(1), .Cells(.Cells.Count).End(xlToLeft))
End With

Dim drg As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Kontrollübersicht").Range("B19")
    Set drg = .Resize(, srg.Columns.Count)
End With

drg.Value = srg.Value
```

Or similarly...

```vb
Dim srg As Range
Set srg = sourceworkbook.Sheets("Kontrollübersicht").UsedRange.Rows(1)

Dim drg As Range
Set drg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Kontrollübersicht").Range("B19").Resize(, srg.Columns.Count)

drg.Value = srg.Value
```